# parameterized queries in oursql

Tags: python, mysql, database

I would appreciate if someone can tell me whether parameterized queries with named placeholders are possible in `oursql`, a python module for interacting with MySQL databases.

For example, I tried the sort of query one can use with sqlite3

```
c.execute('''select * from records where id=:id''', {"id": 2})
```

It did not work. I get a ProgrammingError in syntax. I was wondering if there is another way to do this in `oursql`.

If it is not possible in `oursql` do you know of another python module that can be used to interact with MySQL databases that allows parameterized queries with named placeholders.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The oursql documentation says it uses [qmark notation](http://packages.python.org/oursql/tutorial.html#executing-queries) which I don't think is compatible with this style of formatting. You are looking for a DB API that supports "pyformat". (See [DB API specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) under "paramstyle".)

My experience is with [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html), which does support the "pyformat" paramstyle, where your query could be written:

```
c.execute("""SELECT * FROM records WHERE id = %(id)s""", {"id": 2})
```