# Which Python MySQL client libraries support named parameters?

Tags: python, mysql, named-parameters

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929364/python-best-practice-and-securest-to-connect-to-mysql-and-execute-queries/7929842#7929842) and [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) we can Python MySQL client libraries might support a variety of parameter styles.

In the real world, not so much.

```
>>> pymysql.paramstyle
'format'

>>> MySQLdb.paramstyle
'format'

>>> oursql.paramstyle
'qmark'
```

Are there any client libraries that support a more readable paramstyle, like named or even pyformat?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10986040/1487413) seems to indicate the venerable MySQLdb module supports the pyformat style. However, MySQLdb doesn't properly parameterize queries -- it does escaping in Python instead of passing the parameters to MySQL separately.

Comment: So, then, why doesn't MySQLdb *say* it supports 'pyformat'? It seems to be that the paramstyle must return a string of one type, instead of a list of types.